# Java - Understanding returning type for private final custom type

Tags: java

I am trying to understand the code below where the return type is seen as incompatible.

```
 return new PassLine(One, Two, roll);
 incompatible types: PassLine cannot be converted to TheDie
```

Hopefully someone can shed some light so that I can proceed.

I am expecting to get the sum of the roll for dieOne + dieTwo.

```
public class PassLine {
    private int thePoint;

    private final TheDie dieOne;
    private final TheDie dieTwo;
    private final TheDie rollTheDie;

    public PassLine(TheDie dieOne, TheDie dieTwo, TheDie rollTheDie) {
        super();
        this.dieOne = dieOne;
        this.dieTwo = dieTwo;
        this.rollTheDie = rollTheDie;
    }

    public TheDie dieOne() {
        TheDie obj = new TheDie();
        obj.rollTheDie();
        return dieOne;
    }

    public TheDie dieTwo() {
        TheDie obj = new TheDie();
        obj.rollTheDie();
        return dieTwo;
    }

    public TheDie rollTheDie() {
        dieOne();
        dieTwo();
        return rollTheDie;
    }

        public PassLine passLine() {

    TheDie One = dieOne();
    TheDie Two = dieTwo();
    TheDie roll = rollTheDie();

    return new PassLine(One, Two, roll);
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

From - public final class TheDie

```
    public int rollTheDie() {

    Random rand = new Random();
    oneDie = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;

    return oneDie;

    }
```

The new error message is as:

on:
         return new PassLine(one, two, roll);

error:

```
     Incompatible Type: TheDiecannot be converted to String
     Incompatible Type: TheDiecannot be converted to String
     Introduce...
     May split declaration into a declaration and assignment 
     Flip operands of the binary operator
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the error can't be more clear,

```
public TheDie PassLine() {

    TheDie One = dieOne();
    TheDie Two = dieTwo();
    TheDie roll = rollTheDie();

    return new PassLine(One, Two, roll);
}
```

You specify that the method should return a `TheDie` object while you return a `PassLine` object.

As per your error message

> incompatible types: PassLine cannot be converted to TheDie

Both types are not compatible, change your method to

```
public PassLine PassLine() {

    TheDie One = dieOne();
    TheDie Two = dieTwo();
    TheDie roll = rollTheDie();

    return new PassLine(One, Two, roll);
}
```

Perhaps you really want to return a `TheDie` by calling a method which really return `TheDie` on the new `PassLine` object.

Comment: Nice, Thanks for the explanation.
with now returning the correct type it says that 
-- incompatible types: TheDie cannot be converted to String --
That modified the error type

Comment: @S_HereToLearn Please post your new return statement.

Comment: @S_HereToLearn Your new method is correct. Perhaps there is a method that you did not add where your return a string while you should return a `PassLine` ?

Comment: Your current class compiles just fine for me.

Comment: Thanks. 
See where I added From - public final class TheDie, that is the only class called from outside of this class. Could that be the problem?

Comment: @S_HereToLearn Nope, please post the new error message. Also, if you use an IDE try doing a clean and build.

Comment: Updated. What I understand from this new error message is that there return statement doesn't accept the value passed.
Can I use in cases like that something such as toString() ..

Comment: @S_HereToLearn According to your code you should not use `toString` as you expect `TheDie` type. Have you tried doing a clean n build ? It seems the compiled code is not the same you show us.

Comment: Uhm. I am on Netbeans and pushing to code to GitLab. I have executed the clean and build but that didn't solve, after doing a push to gitlab and reloading the build, the error is gone. Not sure what is the correlation on this situation

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help on this question

Answer (score 1):

The method `PassLine` (odd name, same name as the class...) is declared to return a `TheDie` object, but returns a `PassLine` object, so the error.

You must either change the return type of the method to `PassLine` or return a `TheDie` object.

Did you really want to have a method with the same name of the class? Is it not a badly edited constructor?

Please note: Java naming conventions are:

- lowerCamelCase for package names and method names
- UpperCamelCase for Class and interface names

You have a class `PassLine` with a method `PassLine` (should be `passLine`)

Comment: Thanks for the help on definitions. That was a clear explanation

Comment: The method is already named `passLine`, `PassLine` is it the return type.

Comment: Now it is, before the edit there was a `PassLine` method with return type `TheDie`

Answer (score 0):

You have two different class types: TheDie and PassLine. Assuming TheDie is not a class that extends form PassLine, you're going to have incompatible type since

```
public TheDie PassLine() {
        ...
        return new PassLine(One, Two, roll);
    }
```

the method header states that you should be returning an object of TheDie.

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
public TheDie PassLine() {

TheDie One = dieOne();
TheDie Two = dieTwo();
TheDie roll = rollTheDie();

return new PassLine(One, Two, roll);
}
```

You are trying to return PassLine as TheDie.
Change `public TheDie PassLine()` to `public PassLine PassLine()`